# c# ObservableCollection: How to implement CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, observablecollection

I am wondering how to use ObservableCollection and CollectionChanged event. I have a Canvas class which draw strokes on it. Do I placed the CollectionChanged event handler in Canvas class and listen to the collection changes or do I put in a model hosted the collection of strokes.

```
public partial class CollectionBindingPage : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<Object> c;

    public CollectionBindingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        c.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { 
            //Update the display when strokes was added or removed.
        };
    }


    public class Object
    {
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string B { get; set; }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Object> collection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sorry I am first time using this.

Comment: You bind the collection property to the ItemsSource property of the Canvas.  That's all you have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e` is of Type `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` It contains the `NewItems`, `OldItems` and the `Action`.

```
c.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { 
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Action}");
    // check e.Action and draw your stuff       
};
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

**Sketch for the solution mentioned in the comments**

```
class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _a;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set
        {
            _a = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

class Pagey : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyObject> c = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();

    // somwhere in your code 
    c.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in args.NewItems.Cast<MyObject>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += OnChanged;
            }
        }

        if(args.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in args.OldItems.Cast<MyObject>())
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnChanged;
            }
        }

        Redraw();
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Redraw();
    }

    private void Redraw()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused where I should place the event.. In model class or the view class

Comment: Mabe you should move the handler to a function `public OnChange(object sender, CollectionChangeEventArgs e) {}` instead of using a lambda, because you should unsubscribe (with `c.CollectionChanged  -= OnChange;`) the event if you unload the view. It has to be in the view, because you want to do something in the view.

Comment: If you want the View to respond to the changes, then the View should be the one to listens for the Event

Comment: Thanks .. what about the item inside the list get modified? and the answer about e.Element I couldn't find that property. Only have newItems and oldItems and they both IList

Comment: items within the list should implement INotifiyPropertyChanged

Comment: Ahh sorry I linked the wrong one. Yes, use newItems and olditems

Comment: Do you mean in the item class itself or the class hosting the List.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right approach for just triggering a redraw cycle. The easy way would be to add an event (e.g. `ObjectsChanged`) to your ViewModel and subscribe to it in your View. Every method that manipulates objects, is fireing this event. Handling the subscriptions to the PropertyChange event of each Object is not that easy.

Comment: I've sketched a possible solution that will trigger a redraw if the collection changes and if the property `A` of `MyObject` changes. See my edit.

Comment: Why there are two foreach loops : One is adding property change and second remove it again.... I would guess the second loop should be oldItems instead of newItems

Comment: It is `OldItems` as you can see. But as I said. It is only a sketch. There are still some corner cases. If you only use Add and Remove it should work fine.